# Windows Forms stateful form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to make my Windows Form (`System.Windows.Forms.Form`) "stateful" - that is, it (or the fields therein) should keep the data I entered, also if I close and reopen the application, if possible even when the application breaks (uncaught exception).

What is the easiest way to implement this? Is there some support for this out of the box (possibly without writing a single line of code) or will I have to implement such a function myself?

Comment: Just don't close the window and you won't lose the Form's member values.  If necessary use the FormClosing event to hide it and cancel the close attempt with `e.Cancel = true;`  Or use a dialog, ShowDialog() hides the window but doesn't dispose it.

Comment: @HansPassant how would that survive a closed application (i.e. TaskManager)?

Comment: It doesn't of course.  You'll have to persist the data to disk if it needs to survive beyond the end of the program.  Many ways to do that, the answer you got is certainly one approach.  Saving data when the user kills your app with Task Manager is both unpractical and dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Application settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx). You can bind properties of WinForms controls to the settings using forms designer. Settings can be stored on per user or per application basis.